# Loading .mdf database in vscode on mac

Tags: sql, sql-server, macos, visual-studio-code

I am currently learning t-sql. I downloaded AdventureWorksLT.mdf file to run some tests. However, I do not know how to load the mdf file in vscode on mac.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You need an SQL Server instance : [SQL Server on Mac](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62513/sql-server-on-mac)

Comment: SQL server on mac requires running windows virtually on my mac. Is there any other options? I am working on vscode and I need to connect to this local database (AdventureWorksLT.mdf)

Comment: No, you need a windows machine (or learn with a different mac compatible database like MySQL)

Answer (score 0):

you need to install SQL Server (Express), and attach the MDF to that. Subsequently you can use a SQL connection to connect and access the database.

Comment: I wanna work on the macOS. I don't want to install windows virtually in order to install the SQL Server. However, I am using vscode and I just wanna connect to this local database. I installed docker but I don't know how to use it in order to load the database.

Comment: how about a docker container with sql server in linux on your mac? see this link (didn't test it - just found it googling): https://medium.com/@reverentgeek/sql-server-running-on-a-mac-3efafda48861 subsequently, just script the restore command (google how).